# interfacing a transducer to a pic16f877a

Tags: sensor

I have a pressure transducer with an out put of 4-20mA and having problems in interfaceing it with a pic16f877a micro-controller

Comment: Do you have a better description of what you've tried or even better a schematic? You can edit the question to include more details and links and press ctrl-M to insert a schematic.

Comment: Provide a link to the pressure transducer or tell us what you know about connecting its output - is it powered via the 4-20mA output port? Is there a separate power connection? Are you wanting to read an analogue voltage or just have a trip circuit feeding the PIC? What do you want to do precisely?

Answer (score 1):

The PIC can't sense current directly, but it can sense voltage.  You therefore need a current to voltage converter, better known as a *resistor*.  Let's say the PIC is running from a 5 V supply, and we want to leave a little headroom at the top end, so let's aim for 20 mA mapping to 4.5 V.  From here it's just Ohm's law to determine the resistance.  4.5V / 20mA = 225Ω.  You could use the standard value of 240 Ω 1%, which would give you 240Ω x 20mA = 4.8 V at the high end.

The low end of 4 mA results in 240Ω x 4mA = 960 mV.  The full scale sensor range will therefore be 960 mV to 4.8 V as presented to a PIC A/D input.  Since that PIC has a 10 bit A/D, the full sensor range will be the digital range of about 196 to 982.  There are various sources of error in the system, so it would be good to measure known values and store the resulting calibration values in the non-volatile memory of the PIC.  The PIC can then perform correction on individual readings before passing them on or using them internally.